# lambda wrappers in javascript/jquery -- why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda

What (if anything) is the functional difference between the following to pieces of code and, why would one be preferred.

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(Document).delegate('.ResponseCell', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
            $(this).closest('td').addClass('hover');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr, td, a').removeClass('hover');
        }
    });
});
```

verse this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(Document).delegate('.ResponseCell', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
            $(this).closest('td').addClass('hover');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr, td, a').removeClass('hover');
        }
    });
});
$(function () {
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

This is only about lambda wrapper -- which just gets executed immediately by the $(), right?  So how are these two sample different in any meaningful way.  Or are they?

(btw, I do know that .delegate() is deprecated in favor of .on(), and that it would make more sense to handle mouseover and mouseleave separately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which just gets executed immediately by the $(), right?

Wrong.

That syntax binds the function as [a handler for the ready event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)
> $( handler )
> ```

and

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

---

That said, waiting for the ready event to fire before doing something to `document` is rather questionable. `document` is going to be available immediately.

Comment: That was fast!  Thanks.  in 2 seconds ahead of Hogan... so I guess you get the checkmark... (or can I check both.. I guess I'll find out after the 10 minute limit is passed...)

Comment: While it isn't necessary to wait for `DOMready` for `document` bindings, it's reasonable to do it for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

In jquery wrapping a function in `$()` will cause that function to be run after OnReady event fires for the page.

Comment: Thanks... 2 seconds behind Quentin.  You need to step up your game!  :P

Comment: @Greylander - you could look at the edit history... my first answer was more complete!!

Comment: Was mean all in good humor, hence the ":P".  2 seconds with basically same answer, a tie really.  Link/button to see edit history seems to be missing.  Give you both votes.  Quentin's expanded answer in particular must get the check.

Comment: @Greylander - exactly how I took it.  Plus he has the fancy beige backgrounds... how can you go wrong??